# multiple definition of помогите

Tags: c++

Привет всем, вопрос хочу поинтересоваться ибо не понимаю, из-за чего выскакивает эта ошибка среда. CLION

CMakeFiles/LABASOLO4.dir/carriergroup.cpp.o:carriergroup.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `carriergroup::TableCarryGroup'

Comment: В какой-то момент я перестал удивляться тому, что на такие вопросы дают *правильные* ответы.

Comment: Потому что у вас множественное определение carriergroup::TableCarryGroup

Comment: и как это исправить?

Comment: @Destroyer - приготовьтесь: "убрать повторяющееся определение" :)

Comment: @Igor а где оно может находится??? Я просто сижу, просматриваю файлы уже на протяжении 2 часов, не могу найти в чём ошибка,может есть какой то совет где посмотреть?

Comment: Оно находится там, где оно дважды определено автором кода. Неожиданно, да? )

Answer (score 1):

Да, у меня есть совет. (У меня еще много отличных идей.)

Этот метод, с большой вероятностью, определен в хэдере

```
class carriergroup
{
  ...
  void TableCarryGroup() { ... }
}
```

**и** в .cpp файле

```
#include 'carriergroup.hpp'

void carriergroup::TableCarryGroup() 
{
  ... 
}
```

Comment: или .cpp несколько раз на компиляцию подается. )

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас снова посмотрю)

Comment: да просто скорее всего pragma once/header guard забыт

Comment: @Igor а если у меня не метод а map.
'map <string ,WarShip *> TableCarryGroup;'
И единственное что с ним происходить должно на данный момент.
TableCarryGroup.insert ( pair<string,WarShip *>(CALLSIGN, ship) );

Comment: @Destroyer содержимое `carriergroup.hpp` завернуто в `#ifdef`?

Comment: @KoVadim: Этот каким же образом отсутствие pragma once/header guard приведет к ошибке *линкера*? Это надо специально серьезно постараться.

Comment: @Igor: В приведенной вами ситуации была бы ошибка компиляции, а не ошибка линкера. У автора вопроса - ошибка линкера.

Comment: @AnT очень просто. Достаточно один и тот же h файл включить дважды. В случае автора вопроса - это один раз в carriergroup.cpp и один раз в main.cpp (или как оно там называется)

Comment: @KoVadim Это прекрасно. Но это не имеет вообще никакого отношения к pragma once/include guards! Ошибка линковки, как вы правильно заметили, возникнет при включении такого хедера в *разные* единицы трансляции. Pragma once/include guards от такой ошибки не защищают и защитить не могут никак. Pragma once/include guards защищают от ошибок, возникающих при множественном включении хедера в *одну и ту же единицу* трансляции. То есть это совершенно разные и даже отдаленно не связанные темы. Pragma once/include guards тут совершенно ни при чем.

Comment: Для того, чтобы при помощи неправильного использования pragma once/include guards получить ошибку *линковки* надо очень сильно постараться (это вообще возможно?). Ошибки, возникающие при неправильном использовании pragma once/include guards - это как правило ошибки *компиляции*, но не *линковки*. К данному случаю pragma once/include guards никакого отношения не имеют. (Меня, надо признаться, удивляет, что мне приходится объяснять настолько базовые вещи, при настолько высокой репутации участника.)

Comment: У меня был позыв удалить ответ, но теперь погожу. "... от вас всегда узнаешь что-нибудь новенького." Э.Севела